# Will unassigned object to variable dispose automatically

Tags: c#, web-services

so lets say we have some thing like this websericeclient object

```
var myname = new WebServiceClient().GetName ( ) ;
```

what will happen to this object (WebServiceClient())  is it going to dispose automatically or stay in memory .

Comment: do you mean finalize instead of disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `_GetName()_` method. And on the `_WebServiceClient()_`.

Let's take the example:

```
public class WebServiceClient : IDisposable
{
    private static WebServiceClient viciousReference = null;

    public WebServiceClient()
    {
        viciousReference = this;
    }

    ~WebServiceClient()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {  
        // Standard Dispose implementation 
    }
}
```

If your object implements `Dispose()`, always try to call it yourself. Don't only rely on the garbage collector.

Comment: so are you saying it will be just treated like it was assigned to a variable ?

Comment: @sino No, I say it depends on the underlying implementation of _GetName()_ and _WebServiceClient_. You may think the garbage collector will finalize the created instance of _WebServiceClient_ because you don't assign it to a variable, but if the _WebServiceClient_ constructor is implement like the code above, there's still a reference to the created instance. So, the garbage collector will never finalize it.

Answer (score 1):

"Disposing" (calling IDisposable.Dispose()) has nothing to do with memory. It has to do with freeing unmanaged resources like file or database handles.

What happens when you don't call Dispose() is that these resources will remain until the finalizer is called when the Garbage Collector runs to free the object from memory. If you needed those resources (or if something interesting is meant to happen when they are Disposed()) then you don't want to wait some arbitrary period of time - call Dispose() as soon as you're done with it.